# SonarQube 6.0 - org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException: reached limit of 16000 steps for method

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I have created a custom rule for the sonarqube, Its working fine for a small java file file but when i am testing it under a large java file (more than 300+ line of code) then i am getting the below error.

```
19:41:52.077 [main] DEBUG o.s.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor - Could not complete symbolic execution: 

org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException: reached limit of 16000 steps for method xxxxMethod in class XXXXX
```

I am using

- sonar.version - 6.0
- java.plugin.version - 4.2.1.6971

**Full StackTrace**

```
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\Neon Workspace\java-custom-rules\src\test\files\XXXXX.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:93)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scanSingleFileForTests(JavaAstScanner.java:137)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.JavaCheckVerifier.scanFile(JavaCheckVerifier.java:270)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.JavaCheckVerifier.scanFile(JavaCheckVerifier.java:257)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.JavaCheckVerifier.scanFile(JavaCheckVerifier.java:223)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.JavaCheckVerifier.verifyNoIssue(JavaCheckVerifier.java:159)
    at com.birchstreet.sonar.java.checks.ConnectionReturnCheckTest.detected(ConnectionReturnCheckTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree$PrimitiveTypeTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.IdentifierTree
    at com.mycompany.sonar.java.checks.UnclosedResourcesCheck.isConnectionVariable(UnclosedResourcesCheck.java:50)
    at com.mycompany.sonar.java.checks.UnclosedResourcesCheck.visitVariable(UnclosedResourcesCheck.java:43)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.VariableTreeImpl.accept(VariableTreeImpl.java:184)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitClass(BaseTreeVisitor.java:69)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:198)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55)
    at org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree$CompilationUnitTreeImpl.accept(JavaTree.java:184)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at com.mycompany.sonar.java.checks.UnclosedResourcesCheck.scanFile(UnclosedResourcesCheck.java:27)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: I think you should paste the content of the `D:\Neon Workspace\java-custom-rules\src\test\files\XXXXX.java`. Maybe it helps SonarQube Team to find the cause of this exception.

Comment: this exception is comes with those files which has more than 500 lines of code.